# Why the Esscher transform is the right transform for pricing formula?

Tags: black-scholes, asset-pricing, martingale, wienerprocess, equivalent-measure

A Wiener process has infinitely many states of the world at any time step. Does that not mean that there are infinitely many EMM's for any model that uses the Wiener process?

But then if there is only one EMM for this model, how is it possible that the Esscher transform can be exactly the right transform, out of all possible transforms, to get the exact Black-scholes pricing formula?

Comment: What is the contex for this question? Are you referring to Gerber and Shiu's article Option pricing by Escher Transforms 1994 ? or some other? https://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~dbackus/Disasters/Gerber_Shiu_94.pdf

Answer (score 0):

See the paper of Chan (1999, Ann Appl Prob): [Pricing contingent claims on stocks driven by Lévy processes](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-probability/volume-9/issue-2/Pricing-contingent-claims-on-stocks-driven-by-L%C3%A9vy-processes/10.1214/aoap/1029962753.full)

The author explains that the Esscher measure is equivalent to the "minimum" relative entropy measure.

Comment: Because you put this as an answer, it would be better if you would explain in sufficient detail how the paper you reference answers the question so that others can still figure it out even if the link is broken.